# how to solve numerically space time dependent differential equation in matlab

Tags: matlab, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

[image]

This is a space and time dependant partial differential equation. I have attached the image containing equation and initial and boundary conditions. I wish to get the code to solve this equation numerically using finite volume method.

Also if the first two terms are not there, than one can say parabolic or elliptic equation, here the additional two C_A terms including exponential dependence and the last boundary conditions which is both the functions of time and space makes it complicated.
Thanks

Comment: Hint: [`pdepe`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pdepe.html).

Comment: @troyhaskin this is not pdepe

Comment: @user3355508 - Why not?  Explain

Comment: @rayryeng Only if the first two terms are there than one can say parabolic or elliptic equation, here the additional two C_A terms including exponential dependence and the last boundary conditions which is both the functions of time and space makes it complicated. Thanks

Comment: @user3355508 - Add that into your question.

Comment: But the first two terms *are there* in the image in your question. If this is not the system you're interested in, then you need to edit your question. You should also not expect to "get the code to solve this" as StackeOverflow is not a do-your-work-for-you service. I'd recommend reading through Matlab's documentation and examples on [partial differential equations](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/partial-differential-equations.html) and trying `pdepe`. If the first terms aren't there, then this is a [boundary value problem](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/boundary-value-problems.html), no?

Comment: @user3355508 Regardless of the character of the equation, `pdepe` is designed to solve this type of problem by allowing you to define a source for the terms involving C_A.  However, it is not designed to handle boundary conditions with time derivatives.  So I'm at a loss there.